# How to initialize a zero array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
int M=7;
int N=6;
int i=0;
int x=N*M;
int val3[x] = {};
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
      //some calculations
      if (my condition)
      {
            //if this condition ok, change value of val[i]
      }
      cout << i << "   " << val[i] << endl;
}
```

I want to initialize a zero `array(val)`, I used above codes, but I got an error which says variable size object may not be initialized. is it not possible to initialize zero array?  need your help....thanks

Comment: To be noted: You have 2 variables named `i`. One in the list of variables at the top of the snippet, and one in the for loop. Not sure if it compiles (probably does), but the i in the loop masks the other one. You should remedy to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to the std::vector suggested above, you could also do:

```
int M=7;
int N=6;
int x=N*M;

int* val3 = new int[x];
memset(val3, 0, x * sizeof (int));
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    // ...
}
// ...
delete [] val3;
```

Comment: i used these codes but my results show very large values, i hope it is because of pointer(val3). how to get value of this pointer?

Comment: I assume you mean "how to get the values pointed by this pointer"? If this is the case, then val3[n] for n in [0,x-1]. e.g. for x = 3, you'd have val3[0], val3[1], val3[2].

Comment: So, in your loop, if you just to cout << val3[i] << endl;, that should print out zeros if you haven't done anything else between the memset and the cout;

Comment: no no, inside my loop, i used my calculation and then check output according to given condition then if my condition is satisfied, i want to change 0 by result. i already did my calculation part. now i wnt to see my output. so i used another for loop from 0 to end of this array ynd used cout...but it shows incorrect values(memeory) so how to get value of val3?

Comment: There was a bug in my memset. memset sets some bytes to some value. Since we're pointing to ints, we need to multiply x by the number of bytes in an int (i.e. sizeof(int)). That should work for you, now.

Comment: But honestly, you'd be better off with std::vector. I was just giving the pointer option for completeness of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

C++ does not include variable-length arrays; `int val3[ x ]` with `x` non-constant is a feature of C99. Not all C99 features are part of C++. Try using `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>

// contains an array of length x, automatically filled with zeroes
std::vector< int > val3( x );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int val3[x] = {};
```

C++ doesn't allow arrays to be initialized with a variable that isn't a compile-time constant. Use a `const int` for all the variables (except `i`).
Btw, you don't use that first `int i` (outside the loop).